# Calender integration

Tags: office-365, calendar, office-web-apps, synchronisation, offline-sync

I want to integrate office 365 calender to any other third party calender.

So that third party authorized person can create,update meeting schedule between Office 365 and third party tool using that third party tool and even I can also do the same using office 365 calender.

Is there any tool available that will be sync with my office 365 account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that’s not possible today. It is said that it should be possible to share the calendar, but it fails to even do a simple import in Google Calendar and my other company Calendar (Outlook 2013). The only thing you can do is to sync your calendar account on devices where you have your credentials. iOS, Android, Windows Phone and desktop applications work perfectly. One thing you can try is to share your calendar from the Outlook 2013 client application instead of using Office 365 sharing options. It might work better.